# How am I supposed to loop repeatedly over a "function" in Java?

Tags: java, function, while-loop, digits

I have written a code which takes in a number and multiplies it's digits together and here it is.

```
public class Happy
    {   public static int findSum(int k)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            while (k != 0)
            {
                sum = sum + ((k % 10)*(k % 10));
                k = k/10;
            }
            return sum;
        }
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            System.out.println(findSum(713));
        }
    }
```

and my code returns 19 when my input is 82, because 1^2 + 9^2 is 82.

However, I want to modify my code so that **my code would continue to square each digit and add them together until there is only one non-zero digit left**.

So basically, **if my input is 19, the code would return 1** because:

1^2 + 9^2 = 82, from which digits 8 and 2 would do: 8^2 + 2^2 = 68, from which digits 6^2 + 8^2 = 100, from which 1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1.

What changes to my code should I make in order for it to work?

Thank you,
Dave S. MUIC

Comment: `8^2 + 2^2 = 100` ***???*** it's 68

Comment: oh ma bad hold up i did the math wrong, ill edit it. sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: done. there u go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call your method recursivly by checking if `sum > 9`

```
public static int findSum(int k)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (k != 0)
    {
        sum = sum + ((k % 10)*(k % 10));
        k = k/10;
    }
    return sum > 9 ? findSum(sum) : sum;
}
```

Comment: That would continue if the result of your operation is 90 , while the op would stop at 90, no?
you'd have 90 = 9^2 + 0^2 = 8^2 +... so you'd keep going for a while

Comment: @SparklingMarcel I don't think so. If you look at the last step of his/her example `100 ->  1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1.` OP wants to stop when the result is a one digit number.

Comment: well he's bolded "my code would continue to square each digit and add them together until there is only one non-zero digit left.", but your code would continue even if there's only 1 non 0 digit, but since he accepted your answer he must have explicited what he wanted wrongly

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static boolean check_base10(int k){
            String total = String.valueOf(k);
            for (int i = 1; i < total.length(); i++) {
                if (total.charAt(i) != '0' ) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int result = findSum(713) ;
            do { /* rerun the function until the condition of while is verified*/
                result = findSum(result) ;
               
            }
            while(!check_base10(result)) ; /* check wether number is base 10 */
            System.out.println(result);
        }
```

I think this should answer your question,
you rerun your function until your condition is successfully met in the `while()`

Answer (score 0):

Only start accumulating *after* encountering the first non-zero remainder:

```java
public static int findSum(int k) {
    int sum = 0;
    boolean foundNonZero = false:
    for (; k != 0; k /= 10) {
        if (foundNonZero) {
            sum += (k % 10)*(k % 10);
        } else {
            foundNonZero = k % 10 != 0;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/UhsJ5b).

Note the brevity achieved by the replacement of `while` with `for` and use of terse arithmetic syntax.